# Что значит "неправый глазами"?

Tags: смысл

"Поднятая целина":

*— Погоди, перебью трошки! — Поднялся конопатый и **неправый глазами** Дёмка Ушаков, бывший одно время членом товарищества.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что нашлось у Даля:
[правый](https://endic.ru/dal/Pravyj-31790.html)
десной, противопол. левый, шуий; | прямой, *противопол.* **кривой, косой**...

И вот что имеется в МАС:
[неправый](http://endic.ru/ushakov/Nepravyj-35560.html)
2. *устар.* и *высок.* Несправедливый, **неправильный**.

Возможно, именно эти значения могут быть подходящими для *неправых глаз*.

Comment: Точно! Кривой, косой как раз подходят. ;) Спасибо большое, Рим!

Answer (score 1):

Трудно сказать; здесь, по-видимому, "неправый" — окказионализм. Из дальнейшего текста становится понятно, что речь идёт, скорее всего, о косоглазии или каком-то схожем недуге, отчего оба глаза персонажа не смотрят в одну точку:

> – Я и без просьбов скажу, – отмахнулся Демка и скосил глаза так, что
> казалось, будто он одновременно смотрит и на президиум и на
> собравшихся...

> – Я докажу! – У побледневшего Демки глаза съехались к переносью.